# Type error: unsupported operand type(s)

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
def sync(phonebooks):
    res = set()

    for phonebook in phonebooks:
        res = res | phonebook
    return res
```

This is what I type to run it:

```
>>> phonebook4 = {'234-56-78', '456-78-90'}
>>> phonebooks = ['phonebook1, phonebook2, phonebook3, phonebook4']
>>> sync(phonebooks)
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
>>> sync(phonebooks)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#31>", line 1, in <module>
    sync(phonebooks)
  File "C:/Users/Pinakin/Desktop/finalnotes2.py", line 54, in sync
    res = res | phonebook
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'set' and 'str'
```

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea of what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: Perhaps you should describe your program telling what it is supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
phonebooks = ['phonebook1, phonebook2, phonebook3, phonebook4']
```

(which is a list containing a single string, the fact that this string has text in it that happens to be the names of variables you've created doesn't mean anything to Python; Python is not the NSA, it's not going to look inside your variables for clues about what you're trying to do)

You want this:

```
phonebooks = [phonebook1, phonebook2, phonebook3, phonebook4]
```

(which is a list containing references to the different sets you've defined)